# Regex match value prefixed/suffixed by currency symbol/code

Tags: regex, currency, cultureinfo

I need a regex to match & extract a decimal value prefixed (or suffixed) by its currency.
Here are some examples

```
10$
10.01 $
$ 10.012
61 USD
£ 50.51
94 GBP
```

Found this \p{Sc} very useful, but insufficient for what i need.

Comment: What would be the expected output?

Comment: Just get the value and the currency for example for 10.01 $ the output will be

Value: '10.01'
Currency: '$'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work on PCRE regex engines (since it is using **[branch reset feature](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html)**):

```
(?|(\p{Sc}|USD|GBP) *(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|(\d+(?:\.\d+)?) *(\p{Sc}|USD|GBP))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/oQ6pJ6/1)

This produces following `MATCH` information for your input data:

```
MATCH 1
1. 10
2. $

MATCH 2
1. 10.01
2. $

MATCH 3
1. $
2. 10.012

MATCH 4
1. 61
2. USD

MATCH 5
1. £
2. 50.51

MATCH 6
1. 94
2. GBP
```

Comment: +1 i think it's the correct one. Good to know about branch reset feature.

Comment: Note that other languages use `,` where English uses `.`. E.g. German: `€ 19,90` for 19 Euros and 90 cents.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
((?:\p{Sc}|[A-Z]{3})?\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*(?:\p{Sc}|[A-Z]{3})?)
```

Comment: I would assume that the OP needs two different groups. One for value, and another for currency